# Get mean of 2D slice of a 3D array in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice, mean

I have a numpy array with a shape of:

```
(11L, 5L, 5L)
```

I want to calculate the mean over the 25 elements of each 'slice' of the array [0, :, :], [1, :, :] etc, returning 11 values.

It seems silly, but I can't work out how to do this. I've thought the `mean(axis=x)` function would do this, but I've tried all possible combinations of axis and none of them give me the result I want.

I can obviously do this using a for loop and slicing, but surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use a tuple for axis :

```
>>> a = np.arange(11*5*5).reshape(11,5,5)
>>> a.mean(axis=(1,2))
array([  12.,   37.,   62.,   87.,  112.,  137.,  162.,  187.,  212.,
        237.,  262.])
```

Edit: This works only with numpy version 1.7+.

Comment: It works? One would think so for 1.7 and afterwards, but the docs still say only one axis.

Comment: Didn't thought about the numpy version, I have 1.7.1 and it works. It's not in the documentation but the changelog is talking about ufuncs: http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Numpy-Changelog-103892.html

Comment: Cool, didn't know this had been added !

Answer (score 8):

You can `reshape(11, 25)` and then call `mean` only once (faster):

```
a.reshape(11, 25).mean(axis=1)
```

Alternatively, you can call `np.mean` twice (about 2X slower on my computer):

```
a.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: I think this is the most straightforward answer, though the einsum does seem to be faster.

Answer (score 5):

Can always use [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
>>> a = np.arange(11*5*5).reshape(11,5,5)
>>> np.einsum('...ijk->...i',a)/(a.shape[-1]*a.shape[-2])
array([ 12,  37,  62,  87, 112, 137, 162, 187, 212, 237, 262])
```

Works on higher dimensional arrays (all of these methods would if the axis labels are changed):

```
>>> a = np.arange(10*11*5*5).reshape(10,11,5,5)
>>> (np.einsum('...ijk->...i',a)/(a.shape[-1]*a.shape[-2])).shape
(10, 11)
```

Faster to boot:

```
a = np.arange(11*5*5).reshape(11,5,5)

%timeit a.reshape(11, 25).mean(axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.4 us per loop

%timeit a.mean(axis=(1,2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.4 us per loop

%timeit np.einsum('...ijk->...i',a)/(a.shape[-1]*a.shape[-2])
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.26 us per loop
```

Scales slightly better then the other methods as array size increases.

Using `dtype=np.float64` does not change the above timings appreciably, so just to double check:

```
a = np.arange(110*50*50,dtype=np.float64).reshape(110,50,50)

%timeit a.reshape(110,2500).mean(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 307 us per loop

%timeit a.mean(axis=(1,2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 308 us per loop

%timeit np.einsum('...ijk->...i',a)/(a.shape[-1]*a.shape[-2])
10000 loops, best of 3: 145 us per loop
```

Also something that is interesting:

```
%timeit np.sum(a) #37812362500.0
100000 loops, best of 3: 293 us per loop

%timeit np.einsum('ijk->',a) #37812362500.0
100000 loops, best of 3: 144 us per loop
```

Comment: I think the speed is coming from your call to `np.einsum` using an `int` accumulator, instead of the `float` or `double`, not sure, that `np.mean` uses. That is a risky thing to do with computing statistics, as you can overflow the accumulator and get very wrong results. Giving `np.einsum` a `dtype=np.float` or `dtype=np.double` would both make the calculation more robust, and (I am guessing here) more similar in performance to the standard functions. But `np.einsum` is still a super cool function, so you get your +1...

Comment: @Jamie. That was my thought as well, but in my intial testing showed that `einsum` was actually faster for any size and dtype. I have updated the post with `np.double` timings.

Comment: @Ophion... it is weird that `sum()` does not give the same speed that `einsum()`... very well observed... actually the second faster method to calculate the mean would be: `timeit a.sum(axis=(1,2))/a.shape[-1]/a.shape[-2]`

Comment: @Ophion I think you should post a question like "why is `np.einsum()` faster than `np.sum()`?" to open this topic for discussion in more detail...

Comment: @SaulloCastro I was writing a question to that effect just now. Using `a.sum(axis=(1,2)...` is equivalent in time to the `a.mean(axis=(1,2))` function.

Comment: @Ophion I just saw it! Great question!