# Conditioning and operation on multidimensional (3D) array in Python-NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3-D array (below, `z`), e.g. representing a succession of 2D arrays (below, `a1` and `a2`) in time. I want to select some values for all these 2D arrays along their axes (condition on two reference axes (`x` and `y` below), and then perform some operation (e.g., mean, sum, ...) on the resulting succession of "smaller" 2D arrays.

The code below proposes several ways to do that. I find `solution1` very inelegant, but it seems to perform faster than `solution2`. Why is it so, and is there a better way (more concise, and efficient (speed and memory)) to do that?

Regarding Step2, which one is the best option, are there any other, more efficient ones, and why is calculation `C2` not working? Thanks!
[source of inspiration: [Get mean of 2D slice of a 3D array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357065/get-mean-of-2d-slice-of-a-3d-array-in-numpy) ]

```
import numpy
import time

# Control parameters (to be modified to make different tests)
xx=1000
yy=6000

# Some 2D arrays, z is a 3D array containing a succesion of such arrays (2 here)
a1=numpy.arange(xx*yy).reshape((yy, xx))
a2=numpy.linspace(0,100, num=xx*yy).reshape((yy, xx)) 
z=numpy.array((a1, a2))

# Axes x and y along which conditioning for the 2D arrays is made
x=numpy.arange(xx)
y=numpy.arange(yy) 

# Condition is on x and y, to be applied on a1 and a2 simultaneously
xmin, xmax = xx*0.4, xx*0.8
ymin, ymax = yy*0.2, yy*0.5
xcond = numpy.logical_and(x>=xmin, x<=xmax)
ycond = numpy.logical_and(y>=ymin, y<=ymax)


def solution1():
    xcond2D = numpy.tile(xcond, (yy, 1))
    ycond2D = numpy.tile(ycond[numpy.newaxis].transpose(), (1, xx))
    xymask = numpy.logical_not(numpy.logical_and(xcond2D, ycond2D))
    xymaskzdim = numpy.tile(xymask, (z.shape[0], 1, 1))
    return numpy.ma.MaskedArray(z, xymaskzdim)

def solution2():
    return z[:,:,xcond][:,ycond, :]

start=time.clock()
z1=solution1()
end=time.clock()
print "Solution1: %s sec" % (end-start)
start=time.clock()
z2=solution2()
end=time.clock()
print "Solution2: %s sec" % (end-start)

# Step 2
# Now compute some calculation on the resulting z1 or z2
print "A1: ", z2.reshape(z2.shape[0], z2.shape[1]*z2.shape[2]).mean(axis=1)
print "A2: ", z1.reshape(z1.shape[0], z1.shape[1]*z1.shape[2]).mean(axis=1)
print "B1: ", z2.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1)
print "B2: ", z1.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1)
print "Numpy version: ", numpy.version.version
print "C1: ", z2.mean(axis=(1, 2))
print "C2: ", z1.mean(axis=(1, 2))
```

Output:

```
Solution1: 0.0568935728474 sec
Solution2: 0.157177904729 sec
A1:  [  2.10060000e+06   3.50100058e+01]
A2:  [2100600.0 35.01000583500077]
B1:  [  2.10060000e+06   3.50100058e+01]
B2:  [2100600.0 35.010005835000975]
Numpy version:  1.7.1
C1:  [  2.10060000e+06   3.50100058e+01]
C2: 
    TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed can be improved by switching the order of the selection:

```
def solution3():
    return z[:,ycond, :][...,xcond]

N = 10
print timeit.timeit("solution1()", setup="from __main__ import solution1, solution2, solution3, z, xcond, ycond, xx, yy", number=N)
print timeit.timeit("solution2()", setup="from __main__ import solution1, solution2, solution3, z, xcond, ycond, xx, yy", number=N)
print timeit.timeit("solution3()", setup="from __main__ import solution1, solution2, solution3, z, xcond, ycond, xx, yy", number=N)

# 0.439269065857   # solution1
# 0.752536058426   # solution2
# 0.340197086334   # solution3
```

---

The calculation for `C2` doesn't work because masked arrays don't support setting the axis keyword to a tuple.  Instead you can do:

```
print "C2: ", z1.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1)
```

---

It's also worth noting, btw, that if you time your full calculation, including the mean, your original `solution2` is faster than `solution1`, probably because both 1) masked arrays are slower than normal numpy; 2) you have a lot more elements to look at in the masked array.  Of course, `solution3` is faster than both since it is faster at both steps.  That is, masked arrays are generally slow, so turning to them for a speed gain is usually proves to be ineffective.

```
print timeit.timeit("z2.mean(axis=(1, 2))", setup="from __main__ import z1, z2", number=N)
print timeit.timeit("z1.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1)", setup="from __main__ import z1, z2", number=N)

0.134118080139  # z2.mean  normal numpy
1.08952116966   # z1.mean  masked
```

---

To test the efficiency of the boolean selection along different axes, set the array to be square and try each on it's own.

```
print timeit.timeit("z[:,ycond,:]", setup="from __main__ import solution4, z, xcond, ycond, xx, yy", number=N)
print timeit.timeit("z[:,:,xcond]", setup="from __main__ import solution4, z, xcond, ycond, xx, yy", number=N)

# running the above with xx=6000, yy=6000 gives
# 1.44903206825
# 5.98445320129
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer which addresses the several questions I had, @tom10. Can I ask you why is your `solution3` faster than `solution2`? Is it related to respecting the order of the axes [and is it logical or documented somewhere]? Is it totally independent from the size of the axes (and of the conditioning) in each dimension?

Comment: @ztl: At the end I added a test to show the difference in speed based purely on the axis. I think it's that the striding is easier for one direction than the other. This could be tested by switching the internal representation from C order to Fortran order. I don't think you'll find that the general solution is consistent for all sizes and shapes.  For example, it's not clear whether you'd want to do the slow axis first or second if the sizes were very different.  Especially for a mere 2x speed difference.

Comment: @ztl: also, if speed is really an issue for you, you might want to try things like `take`, `compress`, etc (eg, see http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-01/ )  But these things generally only give a small factor of improvement (1x-3x) and one should always consider whether it's necessary to spend chasing these.

Comment: OK I think I better understand the possible reasons for this, especially with the interesting link you report. Thanks a lot, @thom10!