# Calculating Mean & STD for Batch [Python/Numpy]

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, batch-processing, channel

Looking to calculate Mean and STD per channel over a batch efficiently.

---

Details:

- batch size: 128
- images: 32x32
- 3 channels (RGB)

So each batch is of size [128, 32, 32, 3].

There are lots of batches (naive method takes ~4min over all batches).

And I would like to output 2 arrays: (meanR, meanG, meanB) and (stdR, stdG, stdB)

---

(Also if there is an efficient way to perform arithmetic operations on the batches after calculating this, then that would be helpful. For example, subtracting the mean of the whole dataset from each image)

Comment: Do you want to get mean value for each channel for __all__ images or for __each__ image? I.e. could you specify shapes for your desired arrays?

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly and you want to calculate mean and std values for **all** images:

Demo: 2 images of (2,2,3) shape each (for the sake of simplicity):

```
In [189]: a
Out[189]:
array([[[[ 1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6]],

        [[ 7,  8,  9],
         [10, 11, 12]]],


       [[[13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18]],

        [[19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24]]]])

In [190]: a.shape
Out[190]: (2, 2, 2, 3)

In [191]: np.mean(a, axis=(0,1,2))
Out[191]: array([ 11.5,  12.5,  13.5])

In [192]: np.einsum('ijkl->l', a)/float(np.prod(a.shape[:3]))
Out[192]: array([ 11.5,  12.5,  13.5])
```

Speed measurements:

```
In [202]: a = np.random.randint(255, size=(128,32,32,3))

In [203]: %timeit np.mean(a, axis=(0,1,2))
9.48 ms ± 822 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [204]: %timeit np.einsum('ijkl->l', a)/float(np.prod(a.shape[:3]))
1.82 ms ± 22.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Assume you want to get the mean of multiple axis(if I didn't get you wrong). `numpy.mean(a, axis=None)` already supports multiple axis mean if axis is a `tuple`.

I'm not so sure what you mean by naive method.

Comment: Thank you. This is much more elegant than the way I was doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to calc the mean and std of R, G, B.

```
a = np.random.rand(128,32,32,3)
for i in range(3):
    means = [m for m in np.mean(a, axis = (3, i))]
for i in range(3):
    stds = [s for s in np.std(a, axis = (3, i))]
```

while `axis=(3,i)` 3 represents the channels, and `i` represents the colors(R, G, B). Also you can reference this link.[Get mean of 2D slice of a 3D array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357065/get-mean-of-2d-slice-of-a-3d-array-in-numpy)
. And I hope this can help you.